# Exported Collada file from Blender is split up into pieces when imported into SceneKit

Tags: scenekit, blender, collada

I have a terrain object made with Blender.
When I export it using the COLLADA exporter and import the file into SceneKit, the terrain is split up into pieces (like 8 or 10).
This makes it fairly complicated to apply textures and move the object.

Any ideas why this is happening?

Comment: Any chance the mesh is made of multiple disconnected pieces? In blender edit mode deselect all the mesh and with the mouse over the mesh press `L` to select vertices linked to what is under the mouse.

Comment: Thanks - I'll give it a try!

Comment: When I do what you said, the whole mesh lights up like a christmas tree... no disconnected pieces... :(

Comment: could it be that COLLADA has a triangle limitation per material? i know .3ds has it and i know second life only allows 21844 triangles per material (for .dae). I can't find any information in the specifications on this though.

Comment: Thanks Madlaina. This could be very well the case. I don't know either, but now that you mentioned SecondLife, I remember that, too. I guess I have to live with the split up Mesh, since I can't reduce the amount of triangles... :(